# "Unresolved reference: padding" even after importing layout.padding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So i was trying to get some text modifier with padding and it was all going good until I imported `androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding` and the error on `Modifier.padding(10.dp)` didnt disapear, i tried searching if the import is moved/deprecated but i didnt see any changed releated to it. It also tells me the import isnt used so im really confused.

I use:
Android Studio - Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 canary 1
Kotlin Plugin - 1.4.10-Studio4.2-1\

My full code:

```kotlin
package com.example.weather

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.Text
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.setContent
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.weather.ui.ExampleWeatherTheme
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ExampleWeatherTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                    FeelsLike(50)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FeelsLike(feelstemp: Int) {
    Text(text = "Feels Like: $feelstemp°")
}

@Composable
fun Temperature(temp: Int) {
    Text(text = "$temp")
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun BasicPreview() {
    ExampleWeatherTheme(darkTheme = true) {
        FeelsLike(50)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier
```

You are importing the wrong Modifier class. It happened to me and the error can be quite missleading. Change the import to:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
```

Comment: You are going to get a lot of points for this answer. This is a basic thing, and did totally trick me up too!

Comment: Wow I've been searching all over for this and adding that import pointed Android Studio to the rest of the missing Modifier dependencies. Thanks!